# OAuth 2.0 configuration setting

Tags: php, oauth, smtp, google-oauth, phpmailer

I was using phpmailer to send mail via smtp.google.com server but now it is not working as they have said to use OAuth2.0 configuration.

I referred some examples and created a sample page using [Sending email using PhpMailer with Gmail XOAUTH2](https://phppot.com/php/sending-email-using-phpmailer-with-gmail-xoauth2/) to test it but it is not working. Can anyone point out what has gone wrong in the code?

this is my html page

```
<?php
namespace Phppot;

require_once ("lib/MailService.php");
$mailService = new MailService();
if (! empty($_POST['send'])) {
    $response = $mailService->sendContactMail($_POST);
}
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>Contact Us Form</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/style.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="form-container">
        <form name="frmContact" id="" frmContact"" method="post"
            action="" enctype="multipart/form-data"
            onsubmit="return validateContactForm()">

            <div class="input-row">
                <label style="padding-top: 20px;">Name</label> <span
                    id="userName-info" class="info"></span><br /> <input
                    type="text" class="input-field" name="userName"
                    id="userName" />
            </div>
            <div class="input-row">
                <label>Email</label> <span id="userEmail-info"
                    class="info"></span><br /> <input type="text"
                    class="input-field" name="userEmail" id="userEmail" />
            </div>
            <div class="input-row">
                <label>Subject</label> <span id="subject-info"
                    class="info"></span><br /> <input type="text"
                    class="input-field" name="subject" id="subject" />
            </div>
            <div class="input-row">
                <label>Message</label> <span id="userMessage-info"
                    class="info"></span><br />
                <textarea name="content" id="content"
                    class="input-field" cols="60" rows="6"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="submit" name="send" class="btn-submit"
                    value="Send" />

                <div id="statusMessage">
                        <?php
                        if (! empty($response)) {
                            ?>
                            <p
                        class='<?php echo $response['type']; ?>Message'><?php echo $response['text']; ?></p>
                        <?php
                        }
                        ?>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/validation.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

this is the get_oauth_token.php

```
<?php

/**
 * PHPMailer - PHP email creation and transport class.
 * PHP Version 5.5
 * @package PHPMailer
 * @see https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/ The PHPMailer GitHub project
 * @author Marcus Bointon (Synchro/coolbru) <phpmailer@synchromedia.co.uk>
 * @author Jim Jagielski (jimjag) <jimjag@gmail.com>
 * @author Andy Prevost (codeworxtech) <codeworxtech@users.sourceforge.net>
 * @author Brent R. Matzelle (original founder)
 * @copyright 2012 - 2020 Marcus Bointon
 * @copyright 2010 - 2012 Jim Jagielski
 * @copyright 2004 - 2009 Andy Prevost
 * @license http://www.gnu.org/copyleft/lesser.html GNU Lesser General Public License
 * @note This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful - WITHOUT
 * ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of MERCHANTABILITY or
 * FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
 */

/**
 * Get an OAuth2 token from an OAuth2 provider.
 * * Install this script on your server so that it's accessible
 * as [https/http]://<yourdomain>/<folder>/get_oauth_token.php
 * e.g.: http://localhost/phpmailer/get_oauth_token.php
 * * Ensure dependencies are installed with 'composer install'
 * * Set up an app in your Google/Yahoo/Microsoft account
 * * Set the script address as the app's redirect URL
 * If no refresh token is obtained when running this file,
 * revoke access to your app and run the script again.
 */

namespace PHPMailer\PHPMailer;

/**
 * Aliases for League Provider Classes
 * Make sure you have added these to your composer.json and run `composer install`
 * Plenty to choose from here:
 * @see http://oauth2-client.thephpleague.com/providers/thirdparty/
 */
//@see https://github.com/thephpleague/oauth2-google
use League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\Google;
//@see https://packagist.org/packages/hayageek/oauth2-yahoo
use Hayageek\OAuth2\Client\Provider\Yahoo;
//@see https://github.com/stevenmaguire/oauth2-microsoft
use Stevenmaguire\OAuth2\Client\Provider\Microsoft;

if (!isset($_GET['code']) && !isset($_GET['provider'])) {
    ?>
<html>
<body>Select Provider:<br>
<a href='?provider=Google'>Google</a><br>
<a href='?provider=Yahoo'>Yahoo</a><br>
<a href='?provider=Microsoft'>Microsoft/Outlook/Hotmail/Live/Office365</a><br>
</body>
</html>
    <?php
    exit;
}

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

session_start();

$providerName = '';

if (array_key_exists('provider', $_GET)) {
    $providerName = $_GET['provider'];
    $_SESSION['provider'] = $providerName;
} elseif (array_key_exists('provider', $_SESSION)) {
    $providerName = $_SESSION['provider'];
}
if (!in_array($providerName, ['Google', 'Microsoft', 'Yahoo'])) {
    exit('Only Google, Microsoft and Yahoo OAuth2 providers are currently supported in this script.');
}

//These details are obtained by setting up an app in the Google developer console,
//or whichever provider you're using.
$clientId = 'random.apps.googleusercontent.com';
$clientSecret = 'random_key';

//If this automatic URL doesn't work, set it yourself manually to the URL of this script
$redirectUri = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? 'https://' : 'http://') . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
//$redirectUri = 'http://localhost/PHPMailer/redirect';

$params = [
    'clientId' => $clientId,
    'clientSecret' => $clientSecret,
    'redirectUri' => $redirectUri,
    'accessType' => 'offline'
];

$options = [];
$provider = null;

switch ($providerName) {
    case 'Google':
        $provider = new Google($params);
        $options = [
            'scope' => [
                'https://mail.google.com/'
            ]
        ];
        break;
    case 'Yahoo':
        $provider = new Yahoo($params);
        break;
    case 'Microsoft':
        $provider = new Microsoft($params);
        $options = [
            'scope' => [
                'wl.imap',
                'wl.offline_access'
            ]
        ];
        break;
}

if (null === $provider) {
    exit('Provider missing');
}

if (!isset($_GET['code'])) {
    //If we don't have an authorization code then get one
    $authUrl = $provider->getAuthorizationUrl($options);
    $_SESSION['oauth2state'] = $provider->getState();
    header('Location: ' . $authUrl);
    exit;
    //Check given state against previously stored one to mitigate CSRF attack
} elseif (empty($_GET['state']) || ($_GET['state'] !== $_SESSION['oauth2state'])) {
    unset($_SESSION['oauth2state']);
    unset($_SESSION['provider']);
    exit('Invalid state');
} else {
    unset($_SESSION['provider']);
    //Try to get an access token (using the authorization code grant)
    $token = $provider->getAccessToken(
        'authorization_code',
        [
            'code' => $_GET['code']
        ]
    );
    //Use this to interact with an API on the users behalf
    //Use this to get a new access token if the old one expires
    echo 'Refresh Token: ', $token->getRefreshToken();
}
```

when form is submitted, an error is displayed

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Phppot\SMTP' not found in lib/MailService.php:31 Stack trace: #0 index.php(7): Phppot\MailService->sendContactMail(Array) #1 {main} thrown in lib/MailService.php on line 31

EDITED

this is my MailService.php file

```
<?php
namespace Phppot;

use Phppot\Config;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

class MailService
{

    function sendContactMail($postValues)
    {
        $name = $postValues["userName"];
        $email = $postValues["userEmail"];
        $subject = $postValues["subject"];
        $content = $postValues["content"];

        require_once __DIR__ . '/Config.php';
        $recipientArray = explode(",", Config::RECIPIENT_EMAIL);

        require_once __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';
        $mail = new PHPMailer(true);

        // Comment the following lines of code till $mail->Port to send
        // mail using phpmail instead of smtp.
        $mail->isSMTP();
        //Enable SMTP debugging
        //SMTP::DEBUG_OFF = off (for production use)
        //SMTP::DEBUG_CLIENT = client messages
        //SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER = client and server messages
        $mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_OFF;

        //Set the hostname of the mail server
        $mail->Host = Config::SMTP_HOST;

        //Set the SMTP port number - 587 for authenticated TLS, a.k.a. RFC4409 SMTP submission
        $mail->Port = Config::SMTP_PORT;

        //Set the encryption mechanism to use - STARTTLS or SMTPS
        $mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS;

        //Whether to use SMTP authentication
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;

        //Set AuthType to use XOAUTH2
        $mail->AuthType = 'XOAUTH2';

        //Fill in authentication details here
        //Either the gmail account owner, or the user that gave consent
        $oauthUserEmail = Config::OAUTH_USER_EMAIL;
        $clientId = Config::OAUTH_CLIENT_ID;
        $clientSecret = Config::OAUTH_SECRET_KEY;

        //Obtained by configuring and running get_oauth_token.php
        //after setting up an app in Google Developer Console.
        $refreshToken = Config::REFRESH_TOKEN;

        //Create a new OAuth2 provider instance
        $provider = new Google(
            [
                'clientId' => $clientId,
                'clientSecret' => $clientSecret,
            ]
            );

        //Pass the OAuth provider instance to PHPMailer
        $mail->setOAuth(
            new OAuth(
                [
                    'provider' => $provider,
                    'clientId' => $clientId,
                    'clientSecret' => $clientSecret,
                    'refreshToken' => $refreshToken,
                    'userName' => $oauthUserEmail,
                ]
                )
            );

        // Recipients
        $mail->setFrom(Config::SENDER_EMAIL, $name);
        $mail->addReplyTo($email, $name);

        $mail->addAddress(Config::RECIPIENT_EMAIL, Config::RECIPIENT_EMAIL);

        $mail->Subject = $subject;

        $mail->CharSet = PHPMailer::CHARSET_UTF8;
        $mail->msgHTML($mailBody);

        //Replace the plain text body with one created manually
        $mail->AltBody = 'This is a plain-text message body';

        if (!$mail->send()) {
            $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => '<b>'.$from.'</b> is invalid.'));
            $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Server error. Please mail vincy@phppot.com'));
        } else {
            $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'message', 'text' => 'Thank you, I will get back to you shortly.'));
        }
        return $output;
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is in your `MailService.php` file, which you have not shown here. Most likely a namespacing problem, nothing to do with OAuth.

Comment: i added my MailService.php file too. Is there a namespace error in it?

Answer (score 0):

You have a namespace issue. You're doing this:

```php
namespace Phppot;

use Phppot\Config;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
```

and later using this:

```php
$mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_OFF;
```

Because you have not imported the SMTP class name from the PHPMailer package into your namespace, it will be looking for a class called `Phppot\SMTP`, which doesn't exist, hence your error message. You can fix that by adding:

```php
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
```

which will make it use the correct SMTP class from PHPMailer instead.

Note that there is likely another problem in here. You have `use Phppot\Config;`, but you're already in the `Phppot` namespace, so that will be looking for a class called `Phppot\Phppot\Config`, which probably doesn't exist. If the class is already in your declared namespace, you don't need a `use` statement for it.